# Get latest version in Chart.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I got the following Chart.yaml file for kubernetes:

```
apiVersion: v1
description: Chart for installing myapp
name: myapp
version: 1.5.0
namespace: my-app
```

How do I get the latest version without updating manually every new version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`helm install myapp` will always install latest available version of your chart from your chart repository.

From [documentation](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/helm/helm_install.md#options)

> --version string           specify the exact chart version to install. **If this is not specified, the latest version is installed**